# Does the Greek or Latin "Corpus Hermeticum" exist online anywhere in text format?

Tags: greek-language, latin-language

Looking for the original latin or greek [Corpus Hermeticum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermetica) online somewhere in text format (i.e. not a PDF). Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

Online versions of the Greek text are available at:

- [Ἑρμου του Τρισμεγιστου - ΠΟΙΜΑΝΔΡΗΣ on w66.eu](http://www.w66.eu/elib/html/poimandres.html),
- [«ΕΡΜΗΣ Ο ΤΡΙΣΜΕΓΙΣΤΟΣ»: 240. – Ποιμάνδρης on Greek-Language.org](http://www.greek-language.gr/digitalResources/ancient_greek/anthology/literature/browse.html?text_id=631),
- [HERMÈS TRISMÉGISTE - Greek and French side by side](http://remacle.org/bloodwolf/erudits/hermestrismegiste/livre1.htm).

It is not clear whether these Greek texts incomplete, however; they are suspiciously short.

A Latin version appears to be available on the blog *Pymander Aquarian*: [The Pymander in Latin](http://pymanderaquarian.blogspot.com/2012/09/the-pymander-in-latin.html).

Ficino's Latin translation is easier to find as a scanned version than as text, e.g.

- [De potestate et sapientia Dei (Tr: Marsilius Ficinus) on Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/ita-bnc-in2-00000705-001/page/n8/mode/2up),
- [Mercurii Trismegisti Liber de potestate et sapientia Dei per Marsilium Ficinum traductus ..., on Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/ENS01_LGphi494D_8/page/n7/mode/2up),
- [the list in the BnF database](https://data.bnf.fr/fr/12244585/hermes_trismegiste_traites_hermetiques/).

Comment: Are the greek ones complete? They seem to be only one page.

Comment: I thought the first one had at least a "forward" button; I notice now that that button is not functional :-(

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want? I don't think you're going to find a text for free. I only just found this like 10 minutes ago. It appears to be complete.

https://archive.org/details/ScottHermeticaVolOne/page/n1/mode/2up

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @bobble It appears to be volume I of: Scott, Walter (1924–1936). _Hermetica: The Ancient Greek and Latin Writings Which Contain Religious or Philosophic Teachings Ascribed to Hermes Trismegistus._ Vol. I–IV. Oxford: Clarendon Press. OCLC 601704008.